# How to count # of unique emails in SOQL for more than 50K records?

Tags: count, salesforce, soql

We have email list builder in our Salesforce app. User specifies filter criteria for Contact sObject and builder generates SOQL query which then will be used to pull unique emails by external service via API. The need is to display number of unique emails in Salesforce UI before the user launches the Email Campaign through the external service.

Comment: Hi @max, looks like you already got an answer, but so you're aware there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :) As a reference there are about 4x the questions on the new stackexchange as compared to SO and a lot more active participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @ReadOnly annotation to increase the limit of queries. This is documented here - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm. The down side of this is you can't carry out any DML operations and it must be used to annotate a Web Service or Schedulable implementation.

You can also use database.query(query) which creates the query at run time (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Database_query.htm) like this (untested) :

```
AggregateResult results = database.query('SELECT COUNT(id) count FROM sObject');
Integer count = results.get('result');
```

Comment: How would you count unique emails only? Can you use DISTINCT in count queries?

Comment: I think you can use COUNT_DISTINCT on Id but you also have to use GROUP BY Id at the end of the query also.